# Place two divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been a billion times, but none of the answers are working (Google Chrome 61, Windows 10).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Antipasto;
  src: url(Antipasto-ExtraBoldTrial.ttf);
}

h2 {
  font-family: Antipasto;
}

p {
  font-family: Antipasto;
}

div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div width="30%" style="float:left">
  <video width="30%" height="30%" controls>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  No video.
</video>
</div>
<div width="50%" style="float:left">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Sentence 1</p>
  <p>Sentence 2.</p>
  <p>Sentence 3</p>
</div>
```

It works in the preview there, but not on my local computer.

Many of these answers are not working on my laptop either, I guess it's a graphics issue with Chrome.  Thanks for everybody for helping anyway.

Comment: What is it supposed to look like and what does it actually look like?

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block` to all the `div`'s

Answer (score -3):

To have more than one div. You have to have separate names for each div.

For example. You first div determines the margin. So you would just call it div.

The second div you want tells that you want a specific text to be center. So you would call this div2

Comment: This is not about naming; it’s about aligning them on the same row.